# Oracle SQL - Find the MIN value of a dataset, but exclude a value in the MIN calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Oracle version : 10g

I'm trying to use the `MIN` function to find the minimum/lowest value of a dataset.  The column I'm performing `MIN` on is a `VARCHAR2` column.  This column will either contain a numeric value, or a value of '--' which represents that the value is not applicable.

When performing the `MIN()` function on the column, the '--' is always returned.
I want to find a way to *exclude* the '--' from being calculated in the MIN statement.  I can't use the WHERE clause in the statement to filter out columns with a '--' because that would exclude valid data.

Note:  This is a huge legacy query (500+ lines) so re-writing this massive query is not really an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MIN(CASE WHEN ColX = '--' THEN NULL ELSE ColX END)`

This is valid in SQL Server and I think will probably work on Oracle as well.

As a side note, **never ever store numeric data in string fields**.

It's inefficient from a space perspective and you will get some weird results when doing inequality comparisons.

If you have these rows in your table:

```
010
009
1
```

The `MAX` value will be `1` and the `MIN` value will be `009`

Comment: I totally agree with not storing numbers as varchar's.  The reason the column I'm pulling from is a varchar2 is because it is a view that is using a NVL function to determine whether it should display the '--' or the number.

Comment: @Contactmatt Then I would suggesting checking for references to that view in other tables/procedures and fixing that.  If the data is `NULL` let's pass `NULL`, or some other numeric value that you know to big not really possible in your data, like `-2147483647`

Answer (score 3):

Really you just want the aggregate function to avoid this value.  Aggregates skip nulls, so transform the value in question into a null:

```
min(case your_field
    when '--' then null
    else your_field
    end)
```

Also, as @JNK points out, storing numbers as strings is fraught with peril.  For instance, unless your numbers are all padded to the same length, `min` will probably give you the wrong result: as strings, '1000' is less than '2'.  You can use the `float` or `int` functions to convert your strings to actual numbers, but if you have any other non-numeric characters in there then the SQL will throw an error.